# The security validation for this page is invalid error trying to add sharepoint approval workflow to List in ListAdded eventreceiver

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

What I am trying to do is to attach the OOTB sharepoint workflow [Approval Sharepoint - 2010] to each and every document library that ever gets created. To accomplish this I created a List Added event reciever and put this code in it -

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {  
       SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    base.ListAdded(properties);
                    if (currentList is SPDocumentLibrary)
                    {
                        SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)properties.List;


                        //workflows need a tasks and history list. Here we assume they exist
                        SPList taskList = web.Lists["Tasks"];
                        SPList historyList = web.Lists["Workflow History"];

                        //loop through the workfows in the web and grab the one we want by name
                        SPWorkflowTemplate wfTemp = null;
                        foreach (SPWorkflowTemplate wt in web.WorkflowTemplates)
                        {
                            if (wt.Name == "Approval - SharePoint 2010")
                            {
                                wfTemp = wt;
                                Common.AddToLog(web, "Found " + wt.Name + " in current web " +
                                web.Url, false);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        //Now add the workflow to the doc library
                        SPWorkflowAssociation workFlow = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(wfTemp, wfTemp.Name, taskList, historyList);

                        workFlow.AllowManual = true;
                        workFlow.AutoStartChange = false;
                        workFlow.AutoStartCreate = true;
                        workFlow.AssociationData = null;

                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        web.ValidateFormDigest();
                        docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);                                

                        docLib.EnableModeration = true;

                        docLib.Update();
                        web.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
   });
```

}

I am getting this error-

The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

at this line

`docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);`

Any any have any suggestions please ? Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Vivek got his answer at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175924/the-security-validation-for-this-page-is-invalid-error-trying-to-add-sharepoint): simply removing ValidateFormDigest did the trick for him.

Answer (score 1):

I believe updating this code block:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
web.ValidateFormDigest();
docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);

docLib.EnableModeration = true;

docLib.Update();
web.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

and replacing it with:

```
web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);
docLib.EnableModeration = true;
docLib.Update();
web.Update();
web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;
```

Let me know if this works for you or if you still encounter the same error.

Comment: Did not work. Got Access Denied on web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false; I tried with many various combinations but I could not get past the Access Denied error. Can you give some details of the situation where this formdigestsettings = false worked for you ? was it inside an event receiver ?

Comment: Logically, both ValidateFormDigest and AllowUnsafeUpdates don't belong in asynchronous EventReceivers, where there is no HttpContext involved and the code is definitely NOT processing a GET request. However, such errors do occur despite these belt-and-braces tricks. I'd really like to see a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get all resources and objects that you need from the recently opened SPWeb and SPSite objects.

Avoid getting them from the receiver properties once you have your code running under elevated privileges, like on this line:

```
SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)properties.List;
```

Try this instead:

```
SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[properties.ListId];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practices in getting a reference while using List event receivers is to use something like

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
    {

      // web will be based on the rights for the system account
     // here follows your event handler code

    }

});
```

In your code you are getting a NEW reference to the SPSite which causes leaks. Also, make sure you do use EventFiringEnabled= false while performing changes.

Comment: Hi Marius, it is recommended to create a new SPSite object to utilize the RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Otherwise the code does not run as the app pool account. See this blog - http://firstblogofvarun.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-runwithelevatedprivileges-in.html